# make android source using adb shell command "cat"

Tags: android, shell, command, cat

I want to use shell command, 'cat'.
I want to copy the "abc.jpg" file..But It didn't operate.
What is the problem? Thank you.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
            Process process; 
            try { 
                String cmd = "cat /sdcard/0/Pikicast/abc.jpg>/sdcard/0/apk_backups/abc.jpg";
                process = runtime.exec(cmd); 
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); 
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
                    Log.i("test",line);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.fillInStackTrace(); 
                Log.e("Process Manager", "Unable to execute top command"); 
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little. Kindly try this.

```
    String[] command = {"cat","/sdcard/0/Pikicast/abc.jpg>/sdcard/0/apk_backups/abc.jpg"}; 

      StringBuilder cmdReturn = new StringBuilder();

      try {
       ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
       Process process = processBuilder.start();

       InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
       int c;
                while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                    cmdReturn.append((char) c);
                }

                prompt.setText(cmdReturn.toString());
Log.w("test",cmdReturn);

      } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
Log.e("Process Manager", "Unable to execute top command");
      }
```